# How to modify this while to work properly?

Tags: c++, string, loops, while-loop

I have a `while` loop that searches for a word in a text file. If it's found, I want to print a message. Otherwise, I want to save the input. This is only a part of the function. This loop saves multiple times before finding the word.

```
while (getline(f, line)) 
{
    if (line.find(token) != string::npos)
    {
        cout <<"\nToken already exists"<< endl;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        SaveUser();
    }
}
```

The loop calls the function `SaveUser()` before the word is found.

Comment: As for me then I have not understood what is the problem.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The loop calls the function SaveUser() before the word is found, so it's making multiple saves.

Comment: How many times are you supposed to call `SaveUser`? Each iteration of the loop? Only once if *no* "token" is found? Only once *if* a "token" is found?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Only one time should be called if the word is not found in entire file.

Comment: Your logic is off, then. You should perhaps create a `bool` variable, initalize it as `false` and set it to `true` if the word is found, and if it's `false` after your `while` loop, then and only then should you call your `SaveUser()` function.

Comment: Think on what happens if line one and line two do not contain the token but line three does.

Comment: Then if you think about it logically, you can't call the function inside the loop. That will call it multiple times. So, think a little more... How can you tell if the "token" was found, *after* the loop? Try different things *on paper*.

Comment: @Speevecus Can you provide some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have unbderstood you correctly then you can move the body of the loop outside the loop itself.

For example (I'm using a string stream instead of a file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "Hello Imre_talpa\nBye Imre_talpa\n" );

    std::istringstream is( s );

    bool found = false;
    std::string line;

    while ( ( found = ( bool )std::getline( is, line ) ) and ( line.find( "Bye" ) == std::string::npos ) );

    if ( found )
    {
        std::cout << "\nToken already exists" << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout <<"\nHere we're saving the input" << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Token already exists
```

If you will change the string "Bye" to any other string that is not present in the string stream (file in your case) then the output will be

```
Here we're saving the input
```

Instead of outputting the phrase you should insert your function call.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for answer!